# Receiving Error "No message id was provided in the request." during EXM Unsubscribe

Tags: exm

I am new to EXM, I am using sitecore 9.0 Update1 and I am able to send the mails via EXM by creating regular Campaign but when I am clicking to unsubscribe its redirecting to home url.

This is the log file which is generated while I clicked on unsubscribe link:-

ERROR Attempt to access MessageEventPage with unverified url: /sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx
INFO  Cannot handle unsubscription event. No message id was provided in the request.

Please help me out here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Missing Message ID

The error message indicates that the query parameters that are generally associated with links, when EXM messages are generated, are missing.  This can happen if you are trying to click the link from a Test Message (Sent to a specific email address from the Review tab on a message in EXM) or if you have tried to go to the Unsubscribe page directly.

Couple things to check:

1. On the email when clicking the link, inspect the link itself and make sure that it contains the `ec_eq` query parameter.
2. That the domain is pointing to your Content Delivery instance and that you are trying to open the link using the CD server.

### Resources

- Highly recommend ensuring that you have installed the [9.0.1 Hotfix](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/467253) or upgrade to 9.0.2.
- Also check out the following Blog Series, [Managing the Unsubscribe](https://sitecorehacker.com/email-experience-manager/).

Answer (score 2):

According [to the following article](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/the-unsubscribe-options.html) you have 2 options to unsubscribe:

1. First option is to put the **/sitecore modules/Web/EXM/UnsubscribeFromAll.aspx** or **/sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx** to your email footer. With this link users can unsubscribe from the newsletter directly from their mailing. Sitecore will change the url for *RedirectUrlPage.aspx*.
2. Second option is to create a Sitecore Form that uses the Email Experience Manager Client API or create a custom form with an API controller which unsubscribes the user with the Unsubscribe() api call.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your response,
I am  using option first and i have provided the /sitecore modules/Web/EXM/Unsubscribe.aspx to my email footer, but clicking on the unsubscribe button its redirecting to the home page of instance and log is showing the above message.

Comment: Have you sent out the newsletter or just trying to use the unsubscribe link in review mode? The unsubscribe link only works after dispatch (delivery mode).

Comment: I have sent the sample newsletter with footer link to unsubscribe.